# How to upgrde to python3.6 deep learning vm image in google-cloud compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-compute-engine, python-3.6

I'm using my workstation for deeplearning and planning to move to GCP compute engine workstation. I've deeplearning custom images in its market place with easy jupyterlab integration but those images are based on python3.5 and my code is based on python3.6, hence, getting some run time errors. I tried upgrading  to python3.6 in pytorch deeplearning vm image but not successfull. Can somebody guide me to install/upgrade to python3.6 in gcp deeplearning image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to document [Deep Learning VM images](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/images), it use Debian 9 "Stretch"

So all you have to do is follow this document [How to Install Python 3.6.4 on Debian 9](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-4-on-debian-9/)

By use test package, Begin by editing the ‘/etc/apt/sources.list’ file with your favorite editor(we’ll use nano) and add the line below at the bottom of the file:

```
# sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main
```

Then execute the following command to make the ‘stable’ repository default on your server:

```
# echo 'APT::Default-Release "stable";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00local
```

Now update the package list:

```
# sudo apt-get update
```

And install Python 3.6.4 from the Debian ‘testing’ repository using the following command:

```
# sudo apt-get -t testing install python3.6
```

If everything went well, run the following command to open the Python 3.6.4 interpreter:

```
# python3.6
```